# Java limited map

Tags: java, dictionary, optimization, data-structures, collections

I am looking for some kind of map that would have fixed size, for example 20 entries, but not only, I want to keep only the lowest values, lets say I'm evaluating some kind of function and inserting results in my map ( I need map because I have to keep Key-Value ) but I want to have only 20 lowest results. I was thinking about sorting and then removing last element but I need to do it for milions of records, so sorting everytime I add value is not efficient, maybe there is some better way?
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is it, 20 or a few million records?

Comment: Go with [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Answer (score 7):

There is no built in data structure for this in java. You can try looking for one in the guava library. Otherwise think about using a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` for this. You can wrap it in your own class to take care of the limiting.

If you care about efficiency be advised that `TreeMap` is in fact a red-black tree internally so `put()` has the time complexity of `log(n)`.

Comment: I have to store only 20 values out of milions. Well as for me sorting my map 10 milion times is not efficient...

Comment: You only have to compare your new values to the top 20. So for example you scan 1M records and keep the top 20. You only have to compare to the top 20 your next 1M recors which leads to `O(n)` space complexity. There is no sorting involved after the first 1M.

Comment: If you want to optimize even further, you can store the largest item in the map in a special variable and you traverse the map only if it's lower. If the data is more or less random, it'll save you quite a lot of comparisons for a really low cost.

Comment: I didn't mean a heap, I was thinking about a BST with the largest element pointed out (that it takes `O(1)` to find it, not `O(log n)`). But heap also works in this case I think.